# create a swipe view programmatically xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, swipe

i am trying to implement a swipe view that performs action when swiped using `Mode=Execute`. the code in xaml works properly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="swipe.MainPage">

    <StackLayout x:Name="hg">
        <SwipeView Threshold="100">
            <SwipeView.LeftItems>
                <SwipeItems Mode="Execute">
                   
                    <SwipeItem Text="Delete"
                       IconImageSource="delete.png"
                       BackgroundColor="LightPink"
                               Invoked="SwipeItem_Invoked"
                        />
                </SwipeItems>
            </SwipeView.LeftItems>
            <!-- Content -->
            <Grid HeightRequest="60"
          WidthRequest="300"
          BackgroundColor="LightGray">
                <Label Text="Swipe right"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center" />
            </Grid>
        </SwipeView>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

xaml.cs

```
 public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
}
  private void SwipeItem_Invoked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DisplayAlert("xj", "cc", "dd");
        }
```

but when i try to create the same swipe view programmatically the function when swipe item is invoked doesn't work. here is the code:

```
 public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Grid grid = new Grid
            {
                HeightRequest = 60,
                WidthRequest = 300,
                BackgroundColor = Color.LightGray
            };
            grid.Children.Add(new Label
            {
                Text = "Swipe right",
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
            });
            SwipeItem delete = new SwipeItem
            {
                Text = "Remove",
                BackgroundColor = Color.Pink

            };

            SwipeItems items = new SwipeItems
            {
                
                Mode = SwipeMode.Execute
            };
            items.Add(delete);
            SwipeView swipe = new SwipeView
            {
                Threshold = 80,
                LeftItems = new SwipeItems(items),
                Content = grid


            };
            delete.Invoked += SwipeItem_Invoked;
            hg.Children.Add(swipe);
        }

        private void SwipeItem_Invoked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DisplayAlert("xj", "cc", "dd");
        }
```

why doesn't it work though i specified the mode to be execute. what am i doing wrong? thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try moving `delete.Invoked += SwipeItem_Invoked;` directly below the creation of the delete SwipeItem? Before it gets added to the items collection?

Comment: thanks for your reply sir. yes i tried but it didn't work.

Comment: Based on your code, I did a test , but it works properly on my side.  The alert  is pop up.(` DisplayAlert("xj", "cc", "dd"); `) .

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT thank you for trying. are you sure you tried the one created programmatically not the one created by xaml. if so what should i try for it to work on my side?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code I tested:

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<StackLayout x:Name="hg">

</StackLayout>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Grid grid = new Grid
        {
            HeightRequest = 60,
            WidthRequest = 300,
            BackgroundColor = Color.LightGray
        };
        grid.Children.Add(new Label
        {
            Text = "Swipe right",
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
        });
        SwipeItem delete = new SwipeItem
        {
            Text = "Remove",
            BackgroundColor = Color.Pink

        };

        SwipeItems items = new SwipeItems
        {

            Mode = SwipeMode.Execute
        };
        items.Add(delete);
        SwipeView swipe = new SwipeView
        {
            Threshold = 80,
            LeftItems = new SwipeItems(items),
            Content = grid


        };
        delete.Invoked += SwipeItem_Invoked;
        hg.Children.Add(swipe);
    }

    private void SwipeItem_Invoked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayAlert("xj", "cc", "dd");
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not working :( . does the vs version has anything to do with this? i am using vs 2022

Comment: You can try to update your  nugets to the latest version(e.g. `Xamarin.Forms`  nuget ).